# Common class for HttpWebRequests - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

For making the http calls I use the functions

```
    private void DoneClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string emailText = emailTBox.Text;
        string oldPass = oldPasswordPBox.Password;
        string newPass = newPasswordPBox.Password;

        if (emailText == "" || oldPass == "" || newPass == "")
        {
            PassDiaTB1.Text = "Oops..";
            PassDiaTB2.Text = "Some field is empty";
            PassiveDialogs.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {

            var data = new { user = new { email = emailText, old_password = oldPass, new_password = newPass } };
            jsonStringChild = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

            Debug.WriteLine(jsonStringChild);

            string uri = CycleManager.HTTP_URI + "change-password";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = CycleManager.HTTP_PUT;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            bool IsNetWork = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

            if (!IsNetWork)
            {
                PassDiaTB1.Text = "Oops..";
                PassDiaTB2.Text = "Check your internet connectivity";
                PassiveDialogs.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(PostCallBack), request);
            }
        }

    }

    void PostCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // End the stream request operation 

        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStringChild);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseStreamCallBack), request);

    }

    void GetResponseStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult callBackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = callBackResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callBackResult);
            statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
                string result = "";
                using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                string json = result;

                Dictionary<string, string> token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                string email = token["email"];
                string auth_token = token["auth_token"];

                CycleManager cycMan = CycleManager.Instance;
                cycMan.AuthToken = auth_token;

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ShowPassiveDialog);

            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null)
            {
                HttpWebResponse aResp = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;

                if (aResp != null)
                {
                    statusCode = (int)aResp.StatusCode;
                }

                if (statusCode == 401)
                {
                    string result = "";
                    using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(aResp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    string json = result;

                    var definition = new { message = "" };

                    var parsedStrings = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);

                    message = parsedStrings.message;

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ShowPassiveDialog);

                }

                if (statusCode == 500)
                {
                    string result = "";
                    using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(aResp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    string json = result;

                    var definition = new { message = "" };

                    var parsedStrings = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);

                    message = parsedStrings.message;

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ShowPassiveDialog);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The same three calls are made in several pages, changing the parameters and methods. I am trying to create a common class which can be called to make http calls. But these functions have differnt return types and I'm not able generalize all this??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May this will guide you. I create a wrapper class for such kind of work, its help me a lot and reduce lots of code and effort.

```
 public class CommanHttpRequest
  { 

private string ACCEPT="application/json";
private string ContentType ="application/json";
private string POST_METHOD="POST";
private string GET_METHOD="GET";
public string IsException { get; set; }

public HttpWebRequest GetHttpRequest(string url,string header1, string header2)
        {
            HttpWebRequest getRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            getRequest.Accept =this.ACCEPT;
            getRequest.ContentType = this.ACCEPT;
            getRequest.Headers["Header1"] = header1;
            getRequest.Headers["Header2"] = header2;
            getRequest.Method = this.POST_METHOD;
            return getRequest ;
        }



  public void GetRequestResponse(Action<your type> callback, IAsyncResult asyncResult, string envelop)
        {
            try
            {
                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                Stream body = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
                //write body if any
                byte[] formBytes = encoding.GetBytes(envelop);
                body.Write(formBytes, 0, formBytes.Length);
                body.Close();

                request.BeginGetResponse(result =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
                        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                            {
                                string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
                                DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(your type));
                                var parseddata = dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as your type;
                                callback(parseddata );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        IsException = ex.Message;
                        //I asume your type  =List<abc>();
                        callback(new List<abc>());
                    }
                }, request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsException = ex.Message;
                callback(new List<abc>());
            }
        }


}

public class abc
{
 public void TestRequest()
        {
            string url="some url";
            CommanHttpRequest requestObj = new CommanHttpRequest();
            HttpWebRequest testRequest = _requestObj.GetHttpRequest(url, password, email);
            //if there some body in request
            string envelope = "{\"requestType\":" + requestType + "}";
            testRequest .BeginGetRequestStream(result =>
            {
                requestObj.GetRequestResponse(resultData =>
                {
                    ProcessServiceResponse(resultData);
                }, result, envelope);
            }, testRequest );
        }

   public void ProcessServiceResponse(List<abc> abcdata)
        {
            //abcdata is your data
        }
}
```